# Splitting tables in Latex into two for size

Tags: tables

I’m a beginner to latex and am trying to include a table into my report. However, the table I am using has a lot of columns making it too wide to fit on the page. I was wondering is it possible to split the table into two, with the same headers for each, or do I have to manually create a new table for half of my columns?

[image: Table as appears in the PDF of my tex]

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better option to use the whole page width for the table instead?

Comment: As it stands, your query is rather non-specific and thus just about unanswerable. We desperately need more-specific information about your document. E.g., is it a single-column or dual-column document? How wide is the text block? Which font and which font size do you employ? How many columns does your table comprise? Are the cell contents mostly text, numeric, or some combination of the two? Etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, you are expected to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.